# Исчезновение блока, если в нём нет изображения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем здоровья и счастья! Написал скрипт, который должен перебирать все изображения, если изображения не загрузились, то скрипт должен скрывать родительской блок под классом `.Parent_block`, то есть у меня 3 блока, в центральном блоке есть картинка, а в двух других нет, а значит они должны стать `display none`.

**Но я что-то сделал не так. Где я допустил ошибку?**

```js
let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

image_b.forEach(function() {
  if(image_b.onerror) {
    for(let parent_block of hide) {
      hide.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.Parent_block {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">1</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">2</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Вы отдельно проходите и то и другое..

Comment: Так у меня в Html разметке 3 блока с одинаковыми классами, тут не получится по отдельности. Или я вас не так понял? Если вам не составит труда, то не могли бы вы пожалуйста показать код.

Comment: Ну основная ошибка в том, что `e.onerror` вернёт `null`, т.к. в него нужно передать функцию. И откуда `hide`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Но я что-то сделал не так. Где я допустил ошибку?**

Разберём ваш код

```js
let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

// Проходим по всем картинкам отдельно
image_b.forEach(function() {
  // ! вернёт null, основная ошибка, пользоваться .onerror нужно не так.
  if(image_b.onerror) {
    // Проходим по всем hide??? Откуда он тут?
    for(let parent_block of hide) {
      // Впрочем даже если откуда-то, откуда мы знаем, что hide === `.Parent_block`?
      hide.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
})
```

---

Берём все изображения `.Child_Img` в блоке `.Parent_block` и проходим по ним циклом.
В цикле передаём функцию [`.onerror`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp), при срабатывание которой, находим и скрываем родительский блок.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block > .Child_Img');

images.forEach(function(e) {
  e.onerror = function() {
    e.closest('.Parent_block').style.display = 'none';
  };
});
```

```css
.Parent_block {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">1</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">2</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
  <img class="Child_Img" src="">
  <figcaption class="Img_text">3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Если не секрет, то сколько лет вы изучаете JS и по сколько часов в день. Хочу быть как вы =) 

PS. ловите благодарность в виде 100 репы =)

Comment: Так лайкать нельзя, защита посчитает за спам и удалит оценки. Не знаю, около 3 лет, в основном практикуюсь написанием каких-нибудь задач.

Comment: Практика это другое =) А я говорю сколько лет вы обучались и по сколько часов в день.

Comment: Ну так я ж ответил. Я ничего не заучивал, всё знания получал по факту практикуясь в решениях задач, по большей части благодаря участникам SO, которые эти задачи подкидывают :)